# How to export MySQL data of given time period?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I need to export my data from a MySQL database, the problem is that I just want to export data of a given time period. Is it possible through phpMyAdmin? If yes then kindly elaborate how.

Comment: Please, add table structure to your question

Comment: I think it is not possible until and unlsess you have a special column for storing the timestamp. I think that the reason why even Alexander asked your table structure..?!!

Comment: @AlexanderTaver table structure is very simple i just have 1 column for Name type varchar.. I need to maintain daily backup of the records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Scheduler event in mysql like

```
CREATE EVENT exportName 
ON SCHEDULE
EVERY 1 DAY
DO
SELECT *
INTO OUTFILE 'C:/products.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"'
ESCAPED BY '\\'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
FROM products
```

It will export the table data into csv file every day.

Edit :

Kindly Check your scheduler with this commands:

```
mysql>SHOW PROCESSLIST;
```

In the result table,see for user→event_handler and Command→Daemon. If this row is not in table,then thats the reason for event failure. And set event handler as follows,

```
mysql>SET global event_scheduler=ON;
```

Comment: I can't find the file /tmp/products.csv . Can you please tell me where it has to be located?

Comment: I tried to change the path of tmp file but i did't get the result

Comment: ok, one more thing, do i need to create product.csv file in that or not? or if i have to create the file then can i create it in another format like .txt?

Comment: @Bkay File will automatically created. If you wanna change format change the file name.

Comment: ok thanks so much dude. now for checking this i changed the event for every 1 minute but still can't get anything :(

Comment: Check for file creation privilege. All the best dude.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21260/discussion-between-dhinakaran-pragasam-and-bkay)

Answer (score 2):

Try the [BETWEEN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between) operator. For example:

```
SELECT * FROM some_table WHERE date_column BETWEEN "2012-08-04" AND NOW();
```